# R seems to have lost permissions over all packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

This is not a regular question, so there will be two parts: storytelling and questioning.

**Story telling**

I left my computer shut down on april 8th. It is installed with Ubuntu 20.04 and R 4.2.0. I turned it on yesterday may 2nd but only worked on R today. I started to load my project with `golem::document_and_reload()` and then ... nothing worked. It told me the package `{golem}` was not found. But I used to launch my project with this package's function a month ago (and since some years I work with). I tried to reinstall it, with `{remotes}`. And this was not installed either. Soon, I realized R couldn't reach a single package I had.

**Questions**

Did some one experience such a bug with rstudio?
Can the packages' folders permissions be the key to my issue?
Is there a specific lib path where R fetches information on my packages?

I was totally disarmed on this one, so any clue will be welcome.

Comment: All your packages are installed in (one of) your library(ies). Check `.libPaths()` to see where R is looking for your packages. Make sure that where your packages are is returned by `.libPaths()`, and make sure R has permissions for those files.

Comment: Thanks for this help. It seems my computer upgraded R from R4.1 to R4.2 but did not set the same permissions on the library repositories. This seems to be confirmed since R 4.2 has been released in my off period.

Comment: R probably doesn't have permissions to change file permissions. It's relatively common to set up a library in a location that's not directly tied to a single R version, that way you don't have to reinstall all your packages when you upgrade R. If you search for "R set up site library" you can find plenty of guidance on that.

Comment: What does `.libbPaths()` return? It may not be a permissions issue. Sometimes different versions of R will create new paths for packages because compiled packages are not compatible between different R version numbers. I'll just need to reinstall packages you need in the new R version.